# What to refer to elementary, middle, and high school in one word other than "K-12"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to refer to school for grades 4-12, thus the usual K-12 is not suitable, and it would be ideal to do this with a word rather than the numbers "4-12". What word generically refers to the schooling associated with K-12?

I don't want to use K-12 itself because that is misleading since it implies K-3 is included, but I do want a synonym in word-form to generically refer to that entire segment of schooling as opposed to college or technical schooling.

Comment: *What word generically refers to the schooling associated with K-12?* In the USA it is 'Compulsory education' although Kindergarten is not actually compulsary and upper age/grade differs by state. Or "Public education" (noting that this is not the same as UK usage). Or 'basic education'. Or 'education' Or pre-college.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for 4-12, since that's not a meaningful subset anymore than 3-12 or 5-12 is.

Comment: K-3 are sometimes referred to as 'primary grades' (but a primary school will often include K-5 or 6). There may be an established nomenclature for 4-12, but the most common one is Grades 4-12.

Comment: Are grades k-3 considered elementary school where you live?  It just seems like a weird way to divide things up otherwise.

Comment: _Pre-college education_ would mean K-12 in the US.

Comment: I highly recommend you edit your question to ask for a word that refers to grades 4-12, since that is what you really want and since I don't think that has been answered in any existing question here, and since by a websearch for Grades 4-12 it seems to be a term very often use, but again the term is just that: Grades 4-12. You could email a librarian and ask if there is a specific name for 4-12.

Comment: I actually think your first comment @user9825893y50932 is a decent answer. I don't need a word for "4-12", I need a word for "K-12" but not K-12 itself which was the answer to a possible duplicate question.

Comment: The fact that I'm describing something for 4-12 is only important in that K-12 is too specific. I want a generic word, perhaps "basic education" or "pre-college education", to refer to those general grades without saying anything so specific that it explicitly includes K-3 which further content is not about.